# How to zip files of a directory excluding absolute path in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, zip

I have a folder containing the following XMLs:

*/student/class1/roll1.xml* 

*/student/class1/roll2.xml* 

.

.

*/student/class1/roll90.xml*

I have to create *class1.zip* in /student. I tried

```
zip -r /student/class1.zip /student/class1/
```

But it results in a zipped file containing structure:

*student/class1/roll1.xml* 

*student/class1/roll2.xml* 

.

.

*student/class1/roll90.xml*

I want it (class1.zip) to be created in such a way that it doesn't include the path, it should only include the XML files, like:

*class1/roll1.xml* 

*class1/roll2.xml* 

.

.

*class1/roll90.xml*

One solution is to put this script (`zip -r /student/class1.zip /student/class1/`) in /student folder.

Can anyone suggest something else?

Thanks!

Comment: It might help if you showed your script, but have you attempted within your script to `cd` to the `/student` directory, then run `zip -r class1.zip class1/`?

Comment: yeah i did the same, cd and then zip, it worked, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your script, you should be able to do something like this:

```
cd /student
zip -r class1.zip class1/
```

If you have several of these to do under `/student` you could:

```
cd /student
for class in class* ; do
    zip -r $class.zip $class
done
```

Comment: nice, was not aware that cd will work in scripts. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @thekosmix yes `cd` works. You can do really just about anything you could normally do at a prompt. Doing something like `cd` in a script is confined to the environment (the shell) of the script, so it doesn't affect the current directory setting of the shell that it is executed from.